# not sure why my login won't work

Tags: php

I have created a login so that a user can log into a site, I am using php and phphmyadmin to create the login, i used the same code for another project I am doing and it worked fine but it won't work now and doesn't seem to like line 15, what am I doing wrong.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<header id="page_header">

<?php

  include "connect.php";

  if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

}else {

echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";

}


} 

?>




<div id = "menu">
            <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><img src="../img/buzz_party.png"></li>
              <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <li><a href="advertising.php">Supplies</a></li> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <li><a href="items.php">Party Supplies</a></li> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

            </nav>

        </div>

                  <div id = "login_details">

            <?php      

       if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo "Hello " . $username . " ";


}

echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

?>

     </div>

    <div id="login">

<form action="index.php" method="post">

          <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Username:</label>
          <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" size="10" placeholder="Username"/>


          <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Password:</label>
          <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" size="10" placeholder="Password" /> 

          <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 

        </form>

      </div>

</header>
```

Comment: [15-Apr-2015 17:06:22 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/group 19/php/header.php on line 15

Comment: not sure what that means

Comment: Use `mysqli_error($con)` with the connection variable parameter.

Comment: You're' welcome. I have posted an answer for you below.

Comment: Ok, well you decided to choose another. They obviously took my comment and made it an answer.

Comment: sorry about that, would anyone have any idea how to make the login form disappear after the user has logged in?

Comment: It's ok. It was resolved, but have added some extra information to my answer for you and future visitors, in regards to security in DB and password storage.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer under **Edit**. You can check that out to see if that is the result you're looking for, in regards to making the form disappear. Read it carefully; there is information about "headers" in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the connection parameter passed into mysqli_error(), like so:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Also, you're not sanitizing foreign data from $_POST. You're vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Perhaps give some tips on how to secure against SQLi, like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29654448/3000179)

Answer (score 4):

`mysqli_error()` requires that the connection be passed as a parameter

`mysqli_error($con)`

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Procedural style

```
string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )
```

---

**Regarding passwords**

I noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text.

- **This is not recommended and is an unsafe method.**

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**Edit:**

> *"would anyone have any idea how to make the login form disappear after the user has logged in?"*

**Bonus answer:**

You can redirect to another page with [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

However, you already have output using `<header id="page_header">` therefore you will need to place that below your present PHP codes. Otherwise, it will throw a warning of headers already sent. Using `ob_start();` sometimes works, but not always.

Where you presently have:

```
if ($count == 1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

}
```

Add a header and an exit:

```
if ($count == 1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    exit;

}
```

Or, you can simply use `exit;` if you don't want to redirect.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ You win some, you lose some, *what can you do*. Thanks though. At least it will be made available for future visitors to the question. An extra in Stack's archive, *cheers*

Comment: @Rebekah Confused about what?

Comment: @Rebekah You wrote: *"so confused right now"* - And I replied "confused about what?".

Comment: yes I know thats what I'm saying I'm confused about

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a parameter to mysqli_error():

```
mysqli_error(connection);
```

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp